# MySQL Moving table from varchar to int

Tags: mysql

I am moving an old Mantis table that had a `varchar(64)` **category_id** column to a new Mantis table that has a `int(10)` **category_id** column.

The simplified structure is as follows

**bug_table** (Old DB)

`+----+-------------+-------------+--------+
| id | project_id  | category_id | report |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |           0 | Server      | crash  |
|  2 |           0 | Database    | error  |
|  3 |           1 | Server      | bug    |
|  4 |           1 | Server      | crash  |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+`

**category_table** (New DB)

`+----+------------+----------+
| id | project_id |   name   |
+----+------------+----------+
|  0 |          1 | Server   |
|  1 |          1 | Database |
|  2 |          2 | Server   |
|  3 |          2 | Database |
+----+------------+----------+`

I need a magical query that will replace `category_id` in the **bug_table** with the numerical `category_id` in the **category_table**. Thankfully I am able to match rows by `project_id` and categories by `name`.

Here is the query I am working on but have gotten stuck in the complexity

`UPDATE bug_table b SET b.category_id = c.id USING category_table WHERE b.category_id = c.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to approach such a task a little differently than you do for a new lookup/reference table.

1. To me, the new category table would only have id and name columns. There are only two rows based on the sample data: Server and Database. Yes, I realize there could be other names, but those can easily be added, and should be added, before proceeding to maximize the id matching that follows.
2. Next I would add a new column to the bug table that could be called 'category_new' with the data type that will store the new category id. Alternatively, you could rename the existing category_id column to category, and the new column for the id's could then be column_id.
3. After all that is done then you can update the new column by joining the category on names and set the id that matches: (**note** this assumes the **non**-alternative approach mentioned in step 2)

   ```
   UPDATE bug_table JOIN category_table ON bug_table.category_id = category_table.name 
   SET bug_table.category_new = category_table.id
   ```
4. After that runs, check the new column to verify the updated id's.
5. Finally, after successful update, now the old category_id column (with the names) from the bugs_table can be dropped, and the category_new column can be renamed as the category_id.

=====

Note that if you decide to go with the alternative column approach mentioned, of course the query will be similar but differ slightly. Then only a column drop is needed at the end

If there are other tables to apply the same category changes, the operation (basically steps 2 through 5) would be similar for those tables too.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a shot. However the project_id is integral, it is part of the Mantis table, and each project has its own categories.